# PHP Regex to find words containing both letters and numbers

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a PHP script that parses ads, and I want to add a regex to find special codes, that are words that can be any length, but consist of both letters and numbers in any order or any length. I am just not sure what the proper syntax would be for this. I have found patterns that allow either letters or numbers, or require specific patterns of letters and numbers, but not an almost random mix.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Sample: Buy Widgets 20% discount with coupon code WID2010 by Friday

Ideally, I'd want to detect the word "WID010" and use it to flag the item for other uses. That format, however, is not necessarily consistent. All that can be predicted is the codes always consist of at least one letter and one number, no spaces or punctuation.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: presumably a subject of zero length is not allowed? You did say any length, but i suspect it must be at least one character?

Comment: Added a sample. At a minimum, the target word would be two characters, one letter and one digit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Such a code does either consist of

- an arbitrary count (minimum 1) of letters followed by one number and an arbitrary count (minimum 0) of letters and/or numbers
- or an arbitrary count (minimum 1) of numbers followed by one letter and an arbitrary count (minimum 0) of letters and/or numbers

written as a capture group:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```

Answer (score 7):

something like:

`(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[0-9])\w+`

this does a lookahead for a letter, then a number and matches letters and numbers (word) with at least one of each.

[ideone](http://ideone.com/Ov7sV)

Comment: I have tested and it works fine. This is similar to many common regexes for validating that passwords have at least one letter/number/symbol/upper/lower...etc.

Comment: @Kaii the lookahead/behind/around doesn't capture the content itself. but the `\w+` at the end does. the lookaround will means that the `\w+` at the end must have at least one of `[a-z]` and `[0-9]`

Comment: Underscores (matched by `\w`) are not permitted.